# Eclipse Jface Projection Viewer - no reaction to Ctrl-Z

Tags: eclipse-plugin, text-editor, jface, undo

In my current project I am working with a specific implementation of the jface ProjectionViewer attached to a `TextEditor` nested in a `MultiPageEditor`. 
My task is now to implement a custom reaction to Ctrl-Z, and from what I get this is best done by attaching a specific implementation of `IUndoHandler` to the Viewer, all of that would be no problem.

But, pressing Ctrl-Z while having that TextEditor focused fails to cause any reaction that would be expected. While clicking *"Undo Typing"* in the context menu, which displays the associated key combination Ctrl-Z causes the `TextViewerUndoManager.DocumentUndoListener`'s notification method is called, no line of code in the `TextViewerUndoManager` is touched when pressing Ctrl-Z.

As a possible source of this problem I assumed that maybe a handler might be defined for this key combination in an extension point, since I had previously experimented with this mechanism, but the plugin.xml does not define any key combinations nor undo handlers apart from one that is associated with a special context menu for a different widget.

It might be worth to note that Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V work as intended.

I need to find out what happens when Ctrl-Z is pressed and why nothing is relayed to the `TextViewerUndoManager`.

It would be very helpful if someone could describe the progress how eclipse handles these key combinations normally and decides which command is appropriate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cntrl+Z- undo is processed using `OperationHistorySupport`. Look at `UndoActionHandler` class.

Binding support is implemented using keydown event filter using `WorkbenchKeyboard` ( all keydown events first filtered using this class. this is how `BindingService` was implemented). This will figure out correspond command for the key binding.

`DocumentUndoManager.UndoableTextChange` is where undo operation is handled.

Comment: Regarding the key binding, it seems like an old extension was still overriding it.

The hint to the UndoActionHandler did the trick. Thank you very much.